# How we can determine pages to print in xps documentViewer?

Tags: printing, xps, documentviewer

When I want print an XPS Document using DocumentViewer(which I created it by DocumentPaginator ),Print Dialog only shows me to print all pages and I can not determine page numbers to print, How we can say to documentViewer to print some Page Range rather than all pages?(Determining page number or current page is disabled)!